# nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed WHY?

Tags: nginx

Why is the error occurring?

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2021/05/21 09:12:03 [warn] 1079#1079: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2021/05/21 09:12:03 [emerg] 1079#1079: a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/goodrpi.com:22
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: You have more than one `listen 80 default_server;` in your configuration. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and identify the duplicate statement.

Comment: It'll probably still run and ignore the duplicate default.